# how to fix Tab key in iTerm2+tmux on OSX

Tags: tmux, iterm2

when I want to press `tab`, I need press `tab` two times in `tumx` on OSX, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When I delete this config

```
set-option -g prefix C-i

unbind-key C-b

bind-key C-i send-prefix
```

in `.tmux.conf`, it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it just about your tab button need to replace with the new one. But if it always happens, reinstall your keyboard driver for be sure. The driver must be match with your PC/laptops type or your required version.

Comment: The OP is using a Mac. There is no installable "keyboard driver".

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is really old, but I had  this same issue today.

It turns out that `C-i` inputs a tab, so the first time you press `tab`, it actually puts in a tmux prefix, then the second one is used like a normal tab.

I just rebound my tmux prefix to `C-o` instead, since it is close enough to `C-i`

Comment: That's more or less the same as the other answer.